# Iterate Through JSON Data for Specific Element - Similar to XPath

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, xpath

I am working on an embedded system and my theory of the overall process follows this methodology:
1. Send a command to the back end asking for account information in JSON format.
2. The back end writes a JSON file with all accounts and associated information (there could be 0 to 16 accounts).
3. Here's where I get stuck - use JavaScript (we are using the JQuery library) to iterate through the returned information for a specific element (similar to XPath) and build an array based on the number of elements found to populate a drop-down box to select the account you want to view and then do stuff with the account info.
So my code looks like this:

```
loadAccounts = function() 
{
   $.getJSON('/info?q=voip.accounts[]', function(result) 
   {
            var sipAcnts = $("#sipacnts");
            $(sipAcnts).empty(); // empty the dropdown (if necessarry)
            // Get the 'label' element and stick it in an array
// build the array and append it to the sipAcnts dropdown
// use array index to ref the accounts info and do stuff with it
}
```

So what I need is the JSON version of XPath to build the array of voip.accounts.label.
The first account info looks something like this:

```
{
    "result_set": {
          "voip.accounts[0]": {
                     "label": "Dispatch1",
                     "enabled": true,
                     "user": "1234",
                     "name": "Jane Doe",
                     "type": "sip",
                     "sip": {
                            "lots and lots of stuff":
                            },
                     }
                  }
}
```

Am I over complicating the issue? Any wisdom anyone could thrown down would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your JSON actually contained an array, you could then get that array as a variable and iterate over it.

Comment: I'm marking @Confusion's answer as correct but I decided to cheat. I ended up creating a process function on the back end that just gives me an array of the labels that I am looking for. Then when a selection is made, I just pop the index into the `/info?q=voip.accounts[]` and voila I have my associated account. Over thinking sucks....  Thanks for the help @Kevin B and @Confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. One is to use [JsonPath](http://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/) created by [this guy](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/). It intends to be XPath for JSON. I have no idea how well it works. It certainly isn't standardized. It's not a lot of code though, so it should be easy to understand and adapt. Another is to use [JPath](http://bluelinecity.com/software/jpath/). Both of these are linked from [json.org](http://json.org). I don't doubt there are more such implementations.

The other option is to convert the JSON into a javascript object and introspectively search through the object properties until you find what you want. You can use e.g. Douglas Crockford's [JSON parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).